# EnableDocumentFunction Asp.net XSLT XML

Tags: asp.net, xslt

how do I enable xsltSettingf EnableDocumentFunction in Asp.net/VB in order to use document() in XSLT?

```
Public Shared Function xmlGetter(ByVal strXSLTFile As String, ByVal strXMLFile As String) As String

    Dim reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(strXMLFile)
    Dim objXSLTransform As New XslCompiledTransform()

    Dim xsltSettings As New XsltSettings()
    xsltSettings.EnableDocumentFunction = True


    objXSLTransform.Load(strXSLTFile)

    Dim htmlOutput As New StringBuilder()
    Dim htmlWriter As TextWriter = New StringWriter(htmlOutput)
    objXSLTransform.Transform(reader, Nothing, htmlWriter)

    Dim s As String
    s = htmlOutput.ToString()
    Return s
    reader.Close()
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are overloads of the Load method (such as http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163426.aspx) that take XsltSettings: `objXSLTransform.Load(strXSLTFile, xsltSettings, Nothing)`.

Comment: Dim xslt As New XslCompiledTransform()
Dim settings As New XsltSettings()
settings.EnableDocumentFunction = True
xslt.Load("style.xslt", settings, New XmlUrlResolver())